# Very weird errors when linking (LNK1000)?

Tags: c++, mfc, compiler-errors

> Error 1 fatal error LNK1000: Internal
>   error during
>   IncrBuildImage MFC_Test MFC_Test

Why do I get this weird error every 2nd time I compile?

Comment: Please revise the title of this question to be more specific: Very weird errors is too general.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve fatal error LNK1000: Internal error during IncrBuildImage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001289/how-to-resolve-fatal-error-lnk1000-internal-error-during-incrbuildimage)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug in link.exe. Apply this hotfix https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=11399